# Updated Audio file is not being played when the button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, flask, audio

Currently I'm having a web page that can play updated audio clips store locally in a folder produced from some other service.
The audio that I play when button is being pressed is the previous audio clips（probably due to cache?). Unless i manually close the tab and reopen another tab.

Is it possible to let the  or JS function to load the audio file every time before play

```
<td style="position:relative; top:1px;">
<input id="scream"
type="button"
class="btn"
onclick="play_single_sound()">
</td>

<audio src="{{url_for('static', filename='/screams/new_scream.wav')}}" id="audiotag1" autoplay="autoplay" preload="metadata"/>
<source src="/screams/new_scream.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>


<script type="text/javascript">
#FIRST METHOD
<!--                var song = document.getElementById('audiotag1')-->
<!--                function play_single_sound() {-->
<!--                    song.play();-->
<!--                }-->

#SECOND METHOD
window.play_single_sound = function() {
document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
}
</script>
```

I have also attempted with loading audio as instance inside JS, as follows：

```
var song = new Audio ("../screams/new_scream.wav");
song.preload="auto";
song.play();
```

All the above methods doesn't allow me to play song clip that change dynamically in a static folder.
Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove autoplay attribute

```
<audio src="{{url_for('static', filename='/screams/new_scream.wav')}}" id="audiotag1" preload="metadata"/>
```

Comment: yes i have made that change by removing the autoplay attribute. I realized the javascript function i called is not loading the updated static audio file.

Comment: i will have to wait for 1 min then the webpage can play the updated audio clip.